# Is it possible to enable auth in MongoDB AND configure permissions for anonymous (non-auth) account?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I'm running MongoDB with authorisation enabled, and multiple users created.

Now I want the clients to be able to connect anonymously as well, and be able to perform selected actions on the database without authenticating.

Is it possible to configure Mongo to have the unauthenticated access enabled at the same time as authenticated, and to control what the unauthenticated user can do?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To allow limited permission for an anonymous client can prove to be detrimental to your application. You can never predict the behaviour of client, there is always going to be some degree of uncertainity regarding it.This makes your application vulnerable to malicious exploitation.

The ideal way would be to let your application code talk to the database with a limited set of permissions(eg.read only, targetting specific database). You can expose a few api's that does what is required for anonymous clients.